# Pass variable to execute sql task for create table in ssis pakage

Tags: ssis, integration, ssis-2019

I pass variable to execute sql task for create table in ssis package but show error

[image]

I pass variable to execute sql task for create table in ssis package but show error.
command= "CREATE TABLE ? (ID int , FirstName nvarchar(50) , LastName nvarchar(50))"

[image]

It's "Parameter Mapping" used in Execute SQL Task

[image]

Comment: Add a screenshot of the "Parameter Mapping" tab from your Execute SQL Task

Comment: "Parameter Mapping" used in Execute SQL Task  added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root problem is that you cannot parameterize a table (or column) name using the Parameter mapping as shown.

Instead, the way to make a dynamic table creation work is to use Expressions on SSIS Variables. Good old fashioned string concatenation to build up your `CREATE TABLE` statement and then the `SQLSourceType` from `DirectInput` to from `Variable`

Create a new SSIS Variable of type string. I'm going to call it `QueryTableCreate` In the Expression column, click the ellipses `...` and in the popup window, use the following

```
"CREATE TABLE " + $Package::db_name + " (ID int);"
```

Clicking Evaluate Expression should yield

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Foo (ID int);
```

If you are also building out the columns dynamically, I would strongly encourage the creation of an SSIS Variable `ColumnDeclaration` which would then make the original expression into

```
"CREATE TABLE " + $Package::db_name + " ("+ User::[ColumnDeclaration] +");"
```

The benefit as I see it of this approach is that you can easily test/verify the value of your dynamic statement outside of the component and easily swap pieces in and out as your queries get more complex.

Not addressed here but things you should consider based on your use case

- Wrapping schema/table/column with square brackets `[]` to ensure valid object names
- If there is any chance of SQL Injection concerns, do not use this approach.

Comment: dear billinkc , the problem is solved with your solutions. thanks a lot